# TOR switched bridges

Tags: relays, circuit, bridge

I open TOR with a bridge to a foreign country.  During use when I opened a new tab the bridge switched to USA.  I never saw this happen before. Is it suspicious or normal activity?

Comment: I clicked on the onion logo in the upper left corner of the browser on the newly opened tab and where it said "Tor circuit for this site" it said: This browser; Bridge (USA); Country 2; Country 3; internet        When I switched back to the first tab it said This browser; Bridge (Usual country for past week or so); Country 2; Country 3; internet   I check the tor circuit every time I open a new tab.  It never changed before.  When I originally set up the bridges I had entered the numbers provided by the Tor website.

Comment: I always open searches in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds normal. When you set up a bridge, you add more than 1 bridge to the Tor Browser. For whatever reason, Tor decided to use one of the other bridges instead. There are any number of reasons why Tor would use a different bridge. Maybe it was just time to refresh which bridge was in use, similar to how Tor chooses new guards after a period of time.